# Where to Apply for International Relations?

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions

I'm having some trouble figuring out what schools to apply to for a Masters in International Relations. There are a number of lists I've seen but many of the schools are very focused on the practical side for mid-career people. I'm interested in eventually getting a PhD and being an academic. Also most lists are only of the top 5 or 10 schools so it's hard to tell how good other schools are. My application is a little mixed, some strong parts some weak parts, so I was thinking of applying to a wide range of schools but I could really use some advice in what schools to look at. My undergrad GPA isn't good, 3.14 (3.5 in the major), but my GRE scores are good, 170V 168Q 4.5. I've been living in China for the past 5 years, but only speak a tiny bit of Chinese. I'd love some advice about where to apply or any rankings to look at. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

International relations at the [University of St Andrews](http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/intrel/home/) are quite highly ranked. They definitely give you the option of eventually moving on to a PhD. I don't know much about their entry requirements though; I'd suggest that you contact them and ask.

Answer (score 1):

International relations is a famous major at [American University](http://www.american.edu) in Washington DC.
The School of International Relations is the speciality of American University.
For a nice historical background, it was at American University where JFK spoke:

> Ask not what your country can do for you....

Comment: Hi user3953, and welcome to Academia Stack Exchange! We tend to avoid one-sentence one-link answers… Could you elaborate on what makes your answer a good fit for the original poster’s specific case? Otherwise, this would be more fitting as a comment below the question.